# inserting a value into a dataframe based on a comparison condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, comparison-operators

I am trying to insert a value into a dataframe based on a comparison with another dataframe.
Here is an example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print(df)
>>> df
      name                          
  0  richard Finn, Tim Maltby       
  1  Fernando Lebrija
```

---

```
>>> df2

       Fullname             id
  0   richard Finn          500
  1   Tim Maltby            699
  2   Fernando Lebrija      300
```

The desired output is :

```
 >>> df
      name                            id              
  0  richard Finn, Tim Maltby        500,699
  1  Fernando Lebrija                300
```

I tried using :

```
df['id'] = np.where((df['name']==df2['Fullname']), df2['id]', df['id'])
```

but it gives me the following error:
   `SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 2):

You can do a split, explode, then map and groupby:

```
df['id'] = (df['name'].str.split(',\s*')
    .explode()
    .map(df2.set_index('Fullname')['id'])
    .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
)
```

Output:

```
                       name          id
0  richard Finn, Tim Maltby  [500, 699]
1          Fernando Lebrija       [300]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way, using List comprehension

```
mapper = df2.set_index('Fullname')['id'].to_dict()
df['id'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: ','.join([str(mapper.get(i.strip(), '')) for i in x.split(',')]))



    name                        id
0   richard Finn, Tim Maltby    500,699
1   Fernando Lebrija            300
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also explore `series.replace`:

```
s = dict(df2[['Fullname','id']].astype(str).to_numpy())
df1['id'] = df1['name'].replace(s,regex=True)
```

---

```
print(df1)

                       name        id
0  richard Finn, Tim Maltby  500, 699
1          Fernando Lebrija       300
```

Comment: This is very clever

Comment: @Vaishali Thanks :) my initial thought was a liat comprehension version of your solution but would have been redundant

Comment: @Vaishali something like this was my thought: `[','.join([*map(lambda x: mapper.get(x.strip()),i.split(','))]) for i in df1['name']]` i was thinking would be faster with data..(tested now )

Comment: awesome, will defo use this in future. I added a `stack` variant for older pandas users (:

Answer (score 1):

we can use use `str.split` `stack` and `merge`

```
final = pd.merge(
    df1["name"]
    .str.split(",", expand=True)
    .stack()
    .str.strip()
    .to_frame("Fullname")
    .reset_index(level=0),
    df2,
    on="Fullname",
).astype(str).groupby("level_0").agg(",".join).rename_axis("", axis=0)
```

---

```
print(final)

                  Fullname       id

0  richard Finn,Tim Maltby  500,699
1         Fernando Lebrija      300
```